# Xml script: How do we point our own working directory?

Tags: linux, xml, path

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <attributes>
    <attribute name="priority" type="string"/>
        <attribute name="hierarchy" type="script"path="$WORK_DIR/pvim2vmgr/python_script/hierarchy.py">
            <scriptParam name="subject"/>
            <scriptParam name="test_plan"/>
    </attribute>
```

I'm expecting when I set environment cmd in xterm.

> setenv WORK_DIR <my_path>

In xml script, it'll recognize my directory ($WORK_DIR).However, it doesn't, is there any cmd for me to implement it?

*Purpose of using xml script*

I'm using it to obtain information from certain website and generate a csv file. This xml script is running with command line argument.

*Reason I want to replace Working directory*

When I'm using other person working_dir to generate this xml script, it automatically replace the $WORK_DIR to other person instead of mine.

Comment: Try using `export WORK_DIR=<my_path>` instead of `setenv`

Comment: In my case, > echo $0 indicates I'm in tcsh shell, I should use setenv instead of export, otherwise no command been found for export.

Comment: The important part that you are omitting is what you do with the xml

Comment: XML is only a data container, it cannot be executed nor interpret what you want to be a variable. The solution would reside in the program reading it and interpreting it.